# Join drops variable if it is not common to both tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables and the commonality is the tid.  the $tid is the primary key for tourneys and if it is in team_tourney then the team selected it. The code below echos everything if a team selected it but drops only the variable $tid for every non selected item. How would you suggest I work around my delema.

```
tables
    team_tourneys
    tourneys
```

my sql is

```
$myChoice=@mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM  tourneys
    LEFT JOIN team_tourneys
    ON tourneys.tid = team_tourneys.tid
    WHERE  tourney_state = '$region' AND tourney_start_date >= now()
    GROUP BY tourneys.tid ORDER BY tourney_start_date ASC
"); 

if (!$myChoice)
{ 
    die('<p>Error fetching Tourney details: ' . 
    mysql_error() . '</p>'); 
} 

while ($choice = mysql_fetch_array($myChoice))
{
    $tid = $choice['tid'];
    $tourney_name = $choice['tourney_name'];
    echo '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/tournament-local.php?&tid='.$tid.'" class="red">'.$tourney_name.'</a></div>'
}
```

Comment: drop a variable? what's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fetching into an associative array you only have one slot for any selected column name (or alias).  In other words, you can not have:

```
array(
    "tid" => 1,
    "tid" => 2,
);
```

Your query is going to return all columns of all referenced tables in the order the tables are listed.  Since the both tables contain `tid` and `team_tourneys` is the last table referenced, `$choice["tid"]` will contain `team_tourneys.tid` which of course can be `NULL` due to the `LEFT JOIN`.

Probably the *easiest* way to resolve this is to read the `tourneys` table last:

```
SELECT team_tourneys.*, tourneys.*
FROM tourneys
LEFT JOIN team_tourneys
ON tourneys.tid = team_tourneys.tid
WHERE tourney_state = '$region' AND tourney_start_date >= now()
GROUP BY tourneys.tid ORDER BY tourney_start_date ASC;
```

You should really enter each column name individually, however.  It's bad practice to use `*`.

Comment: I ran into a road block. When using the above sql one of the rows that should be displayed is not, when using this if statement 

`  if ($selected=='Y' && $team_id == $id) {$we_selected = 'Selected';} 
   elseif ($closed == 'Y') {$we_selected ='Closed';}
   else {$we_selected='<a href="select_tourney.php?tid='.$tid.'&team_id='.$id.'&uid='.$uid.'&id='.$id.'">`

there are 3 records all with selected = 'Y' but as I said one is omitted in the result, what the heck is wrong?

Comment: There's not enough information for me to be able to tell.  Are you saying that the query itself doesn't return all three records, or that once you get the result list back something in the php code that is processing the results omits one of the records?

Comment: Yes the query is not returning all 3, only 2, then I added 5 records and still only 2 results

Comment: Well, you do `GROUP BY tourneys.tid`, so that is what is probably "hiding" the other records.  I don't know much about your structure, data, or application so I don't know whether or not you need to take that clause out completely or add another column to it, but I would at least start by taking out the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I removed the GROUP BY and the result added 1. I will keep looking at the if statment logic :)

Comment: Starson do you freelance? I could use some help.

Comment: I found that I am getting double records for items that another team selected. Example is if team A selected a tourney and team B selected the same tourney the result displays the tourney twice. The desired result is that the tourney be displayed only once

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time to freelance.  If I understand how you want to display a tournament you have one of two options.  1. You can either put the `GROUP BY` clause back in and use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function on the `team_tourneys` column(s) you're interested in.  2. You can adjust your php loop to detect identical `tid`'s and append data to the desired column(s) in the current row instead of creating a new row.

Comment: I was able to fix it with this sql  `SELECT  
    DISTINCT(tourneys.tid),              tourneys.tourney_state,        tourneys.tourney_name,          tourneys.tourney_start_date,         
          team_tourneys.tourney_id,  
team_tourneys.selected,          team_tourneys.paid,         team_tourneys.entered,                 team_tourneys.team_id
FROM  tourneys  
LEFT JOIN team_tourneys  
ON tourneys.tid = team_tourneys.tourney_id  
WHERE  tourney_state = '$region' 
AND tourney_start_date >= now()     
GROUP BY tourneys.tid  
ORDER BY tourney_start_date ASC`  Thanks for your help